# WPF: An implementation of INotifyDataErrorInfo

Tags: c#, validation, wpf, mvvm

An abstract base class which derives from the `ObservableObject` (MvvmLight), implementing the `INotifyDataErrorInfo` interface.

The model (exposed via the ViewModel) binds directly to the view, to avoid duplication of properties.

A couple of notes:

a) I chose the `HashSet<string>>` to avoid duplicate errors, e.g. "*The number of allowed characters has been exceeded.*" on every keystroke when `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`.

b) The `RaisePropertyChanged` of the MvvmLight's `ObservableObject` has been overridden to validate individual properties.

c) The method `IsValidated()` validates the object and provides visual feedback to the user when e.g. the "Save" button has been pressed.

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;

namespace WPF.MVVM.UI.Data.Model.Base
{
    public abstract class ValidatedObservableObject : ObservableObject, INotifyDataErrorInfo
    {
        private readonly IDictionary<string, HashSet<string>> _errors = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>();

        public bool HasErrors
        {
            get => _errors.Count > 0;
        }

        public IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName) || !_errors.ContainsKey(propertyName))
                return null;

            return _errors[propertyName];
        }

        public bool IsValidated()
        {
            var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
            var valid = Validator.TryValidateObject(this, new ValidationContext(this), results, true);

            if (valid)
                return true;

            AppendOrUpdateErrors(results);

            return false;
        }

        public override void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
        {
            base.RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
            {
                ValidateProperty(propertyName);
            }
        }

        private void ValidateProperty(string propertyName)
        {
            var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
            var valid = Validator.TryValidateProperty(GetType().GetProperty(propertyName)?.GetValue(this), new ValidationContext(this) { MemberName = propertyName }, results);

            if (valid)
            {
                RemoveFromErrors(propertyName);
            }
            else
            {
                AppendOrUpdateErrors(results);
            }
        }

        private void RemoveFromErrors(string propertyName)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName) || !_errors.ContainsKey(propertyName))
                return;

            _errors.Remove(propertyName);

            RaiseErrorsChanged(propertyName);
        }

        private void AppendOrUpdateErrors(IReadOnlyCollection<ValidationResult> results)
        {
            if (results == null)
                return;

            foreach (var memberName in results.SelectMany(r => r.MemberNames).Distinct())
            {
                var memberErrors = new HashSet<string>(results.Where(r => r.MemberNames.Contains(memberName)).Select(r => r.ErrorMessage));

                if (_errors.ContainsKey(memberName))
                {
                    _errors[memberName] = memberErrors;
                }
                else
                {
                    _errors.Add(memberName, memberErrors);
                }

                RaiseErrorsChanged(memberName);
            }
        }

        public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> ErrorsChanged;

        private void RaiseErrorsChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            ErrorsChanged?.Invoke(this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```